# show different list items on different catagories activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

Now i want to list items in different categories ex: one of them hospitals and the one item must contain the name, the address and the phone number, I created this if statement in the adapter if the index of has one text invisible others but it didn't work with me well any help [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNlDE.png)

```
public class Data {
private String placeWord;
private String addressWord;
private String reason = ONE_TEXT;
private static final String ONE_TEXT = "ah";


public Data(String mPlaceWord , String mAddressWord){
    placeWord = mPlaceWord;
    addressWord = mAddressWord;
}
public Data(String theReson){
   reason = theReson;
}
public String getPlaceWord(){
    return placeWord;
}
public String getAddressWord(){
    return addressWord;
}
public String getReason(){return reason;}

public boolean oneText(){
    return  reason != ONE_TEXT;
}
```

```java
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private int mColorResourceId;

    public DataAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Data> resource ,int ColorResourceId) {
        super(context,0, resource);
    mColorResourceId =  ColorResourceId ;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listitem = convertView;
        if( listitem == null){
            listitem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }
        Data currentword = (Data) getItem(position);
        TextView pd = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.placetxt);
        pd.setText(currentword.getPlaceWord());
        TextView ad = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.adddrestxt);
        ad.setText(currentword.getAddressWord());
        if (currentword.oneText()){
            TextView ps = (TextView) listitem.findViewById(R.id.placetxt);
            ps.setText(currentword.getReason());
        } else{
            pd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
        View textContainer = listitem.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
        // Set the background color of the text container View
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
        return listitem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code as snippet or pastebin link but not as a picture (twice). Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please describe "it didn't work with me" with more details? What happens and what did you expect?

Comment: when i run the some texts don't appear and it's must appear . as : one of list item in hospital category "the name of the hospital and it's address and the phone number " another category example top attraction category one of it's list item must have "one text "
i expected this but the  not happened  , activity work well that which i used the constructor has 2 parameter and others no @Milgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recycler view and add this logic in its adapter.

Comment: i'm still learning custom adapter and arraylist and custom class and practice on it

Comment: my mistake in the logic of the variable reason and it's method , right ?